# Setting subdomains using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to set a subdomain for all site users, like www.companyname.mydomain.com
I would like to use htaccess for this.

when somebody requests www.companyname.mydomain.com it should redirect to 
myfile.php?name=companyname

How can I achieve this using an htaccess file ?

Thanks for the consideration.

Comment: Since you are trying to create new virtual hosts, I don't think you can. I'm pretty sure you need to modify the main Apache configuration rather then using the per-directory approach.

Comment: @milan: Welcome to StackOverflow! Be aware that your question is likely to be moved to http://ServerFault.com which has a focus on server configuration etc. If this happens, a link will be provided to the new location of the question in big gray box below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure this website is configured to respond to *.mydomain.com.

```
RewriteCond %{http_host}  ^www.(\w+).mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$          /myfile.php?name=%1 [L]
```

You might want to adjust `^.*$`, since this check will rewrite regardless of what comes after www.companyname.mydomain.com.

Comment: how can I configure my website in such a way that respond to *.mydomain.com ? I am using cpanel in server

Comment: Dont have any experience configuring apache, I guess thats a question worth asking on serverfault.com.